# Why does CakePHP use different plural/singular naming conventions?

Tags: cakephp, naming-conventions

Can somebody perhaps explain here why on earth CakePHP has a convention of using plural names for db tables and controllers and singular for models? Why not always use singular terms, or always plural?

For me it seems confusing to always have to think "now do I use plural or singular here?" (Or is there an easy way to remember?) And then you have the join-tables that use a combination of both!

I assume there's a good reason somewhere, but just have not come across it *(I really hope it's not just because Ruby-on-Rails works that way)*.

Comment: It probably IS because of ruby on rails :)

Comment: No idea.  We always use the 'name', 'table', and 'primaryKey' optional fields (see the model docs) to name things how we want.  We capitalize what we want, when we want, and leave everything singular.  Other than that, though, I really like Cake.

Comment: It could also be because CakePHP was designed by people who use PHP which is inconsistent by definition.

Comment: nilamo: Good idea. Perhaps I should just name things how I want. ;-)

Comment: Noah: I think PHP has inherited some inconsistencies because different libraries have been added into the base with different naming conventions. CakePHP appears to be designed that way from the outset (and RoR too!) I just don't really see why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> [**CakePHP Conventions**](http://book.cakephp.org/view/22/CakePHP-Conventions)
>
> CakePHP’s conventions have been distilled out of years of web development experience and best practices. While we suggest you use these conventions while developing with CakePHP, we should mention that many of these tenets are easily overridden – something that is especially handy when working with legacy systems.

I think the idea is to make it more fluent to read and to think of elements in the right way. Database tables are always plural, because they hold many records. The model is singular, because you should think about finding a single record with it. A select field for `model_id` will automatically get its options from `$models`, because you select one of many.

```
$model = $this->Model->find('first');  // reads like English
$model = $this->Models->find('first'); // slightly trips you up

$models = $this->Model->find('all');   // works okay
$models = $this->Models->find('all');  // more logical, but "this models" still trips
```

It's not always perfect, but I think it's quite a nice convention once you get used to it. I can see how it can be confusing in the beginning though.

Comment: Agreed.  the model is an abstraction for your data mode, and in english those are always singular (you don't say "what is the essence of cars").  The controller handles multiple instances of the abstraction (it wrangles them all).  IMO it's pretty consistent with how we do things in english.

Answer (score 4):

> is there an easy way to remember?

Yes, with respect to the parts where naming convention counts (db/model/controller)... If it's not the name of a model (ie. `User`) or the name of a foreign key (ie. `user_id`), then it is plural. Everything is basically plural apart from those two things.