# can any one can clear me some naming conventions in cake php for every mvc folder and files

Tags: cakephp

I checked in web for example and I found naming example as:

```
Database table: books
Model class: Book
Controller class: BooksController
View found at: /app/views/books/index.ctp
```

Why only model name should be singular? If I crated all field with page or book means what should be given in model.

Comment: I think this link will explain you more
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752668/why-does-cakephp-use-different-plural-singular-naming-conventions

Hope it helps

Comment: Note your casing. That is very important! And: You should always mention the exact cakephp version you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah only model can be singular, you should use `Book`, if there are fields in the table, you shouldn't have to add anything in the model unless you have validations.

I think this link will explain you more
[Why does CakePHP use different plural/singular naming conventions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1752668/why-does-cakephp-use-different-plural-singular-naming-conventions)

Hope it helps

Comment: 'class BooksController extends AppController {
var $name = 'Books';
function index() {
$this->set('books', $this->Book->find('all'));
}
}' in the code $name=Books , in set('books') whatis the use of it?

Comment: Do you know why set is used in $this->set('books', $this->Book->find('all')); ?